# Crear subominio en wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, .htaccess, servidor

necesito crear una subcarpeta en el dominio  https://www.xxxxx.es
El subominio que quiero habilitar es https://www.xxxxx.es**/en/**recrea/

¿Hay alguna forma de hacer esto? En los enlaces de wordpress no me deja hacerlo y no sé si hay que forzarlo de alguna forma con el htaccess o en el usuario del servidor hay una forma más facil de hacerlo.

He hablado con el servidor y me ha dicho esto:

```
usted indica que desea crear un subdominio en https://www.xxxx.es

Un subdominio es una dirección que se engloba dentro del dominio principal, es decir, subdominio.xxxxx.es.

Si lo que necesita hacer es una subcarpeta dentro del dominio: https://www.xxxxx.es/en/recrea puede hacerlo desde el Gestor de Archivos del panel.

Para acceder al Gestor de Archivos de DirectAdmin realice el siguiente procedimiento:

    Acceda al panel DirectAdmin del dominio
    Entre en el menú "Herramientas"
    Haga click sobre "Gestor de Archivos"

Si tiene algún problema para seguir los pasos indíquenos dónde se queda, el error concreto y qué aparece en pantalla. También puede realizar cualquier cambio en su web conectando mediante FTP.

A continuación le indico el procedimiento para crear subdominios si eso es lo que necesita:

    Entre al panel del dominio en cuestión
    Pulse en la opción "Gestión de Subdominios" del apartado "Herramientas"
    Pulse en el botón "Añadir subdominio" que encontrará bajo el menú general
    En la opción "Agregar subdominio: [________].sudominio.xxx" escriba el subdominio elegido y pulse en "Crear"
```

Mi pregunta es, una vez hago esto ¿como hago desde wordpress para que coja el enlace que quiero?
https://www.xxxxx.es**/en/**recrea/

Un saludo !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado otra solucion mas facil, he creado una pagina **en** y despues he puesto que la pagina **xxxx** tenga la superior **en** .

Answer (score 1):

Tengo tres opciones para ese detalle.

1. Crear un subdominio desde tu cpanel (si es que te lo permite). De esta manera tendrás midominio.com y  ejemplo.midominio.com. Para esta situación, puedes instalar un wordpress por cada subdominio.
2. Algunos plugins te permite tener versión en español e inglés, estos automáticamente direccionan tu página como esté en midominio.com/en o midominio.com/ (si es español tu lenguaje).

   3. La solución que haces para la página, también es funcional.